# create chart with oracle query

Tags: javascript, php, html, oracle

i am trying to create a chart pie with a query from oracle database.
i have already connect to the data base and echo the results,but i cant create a chart.any suggestion about this?

```js
<?php
$tns = "  
(DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = xxx.xxxx.xxx.xxx)(PORT = xxxx))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
    )
  )
       ";
$db_username = "xxx";
$db_password = "xxxxR";
try{
    $conn = new PDO("oci:xxxx=".$tns,$db_username,$db_password);
}catch(PDOException $e){
    echo ($e->getMessage());
}
if (!$conn) {
   $m = oci_error();
   echo $m['message'], "\n";
   exit;
}
else {
   echo "Connected to Oracle!";
}
 
$query = "SELECT T71.C_C1003000015, COUNT (T71.C1)
  FROM ICT_DATABASE.T71 T71
WHERE (T71.C_C1003000015 NOT IN (exelllllllllxx.xxxx.xxx'))
       AND trunc(T71.ARRIVAL_DATE) = trunc(sysdate)
GROUP BY T71.C_C1003000015";
 
$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
 
if ($stmt->execute()) {
    echo "<h4>$query</h4>";
    echo "<pre>";
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
        print_r($row);
    }
    echo "</pre>";
 }
 
 
?>
```

that code is working and export data  how can i create a chart now?

Comment: I can work it into your code if you want. Show me what `$row` looks like.

Comment: at first, i thought someone had lost it. let me look

Comment: i'll show you, just a sec. `$row` is just a string?

Comment: ok, still trying to userstand the data. looks like we need to split the string on IT-EXT-COSMOTE-, get the departments out of there, along with their number value. Is there more than row? Do we then need to total these numbers for each department across multiple rows?

Answer (score 1):

ok, here goes.

you need to add Google's scripts to your page.

`<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>`

Add this div where you want the chart...

`<div id="piechart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>`

then add this JavaScript, assuming you leave the output in the `<pre>` element

```
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
  var googleArray = [];
  googleArray.push(['Department', 'Value']);
  var testRow = document.getElementsByTagName('PRE')[0].innerHTML;
  var testArr = testRow.split('IT-EXT-COSMOTE-');
  var deptSplit;

  for (var i = 0; i < testArr.length; i++) {
    if (testArr[i] !== '') {
      deptSplit = testArr[i].split(' - ');
      googleArray.push([deptSplit[0], Number(deptSplit[1])]);
    }
  }

  var dataTable = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(googleArray, false);
  var chartOptions = {title: 'Department Totals'};
  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
  chart.draw(dataTable, chartOptions);
}
```

let me know if you need further help...

Comment: ok, php runs on the server. google charts run on the client. so i'm assuming you leave the data in the `<pre>` element as you have it. Then when the page loads, the code I've provided will take the data out of the `<pre>` element and load it into the array. But there are a number of other ways to do this. Just trying the easiest...